# NSArray code not being run

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I can't figure this one out, hopefully someone can help.

This is the code in my ViewController.h file.

```
{
NSArray *bgImages;
int currentBackground;
bool hasShrunk;
bool hasMoved;

CGAffineTransform translate;
CGAffineTransform sizeShrink;
CGAffineTransform sizeGrow;
}
```

Here is some of my code in the ViewController.m file.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
hasMoved = NO;
hasShrunk = NO;
currentBackground = 0;

bgImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"WallPaper_01.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"WallPaper_02.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"WallPaper_03.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"WallPaper_04.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"WallPaper_05.png"],
        nil];

sizeShrink = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.25,.25);
sizeGrow = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,1);

_myBackground.image = [bgImages objectAtIndex:currentBackground];
}
```

Here is the issue.  This code and the entire project run fine on the simulator, no issues.  When I change the output to an actual iPhone device it fails.  The code is failing on the allocation of the array called bgImages.  If I place a breakpoint on viewDidLoad and step into it line by line, it executes up to the array allocation line and then jumps over it.  When it then attempts to execute the line:

```
_myBackground.image = [bgImages objectAtIndex:currentBackground];
```

it will fail because the array is empty.  I don't understand how this can work in the simulator but not on the actual device.  The code does not look incorrect but I am at my wits end trying to understand why it behaves this way.  Have I coded it incorrectly?

Comment: What is the exact error? Is _myBackground initialized? Also, NSarray is a typo, should be NSArray.

Comment: Does your code actually say "NSarray" with a lowercase "a"? That might be a problem.

Comment: Sorry.. That was a typo as I entered the code here on this site. The error that I get is this...   ***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason *** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: Check the capitalization of your image names. The simulator is tolerant of capitalization differences, the device is not.

Comment: The images are in the project folder, but it seems you haven't added them to the project. In the xcode navigator, do `Add files to project`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting a problem because the array doesn't have any elements in it. One possibility is that all of the `[UIImage imageNamed:...]` calls are returning `nil`. Break one of these out as a separate variable, e.g.

```
UIImage *firstImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"WallPaper_01.png"];
```

and set a breakpoint on that line to make sure that the image is being initialized correctly. If it isn't, one possible reason is that you have the 2x version (`WallPaper_01@2x.png`) but not the 1x version, or vice versa.

**Edit:** As @rdelmar notes, another possible reason is that, since Mac OS X uses (by default) a case-insensitive filesystem but iOS uses a case-sensitive filesystem, you're using the wrong filename, but you're only seeing a problem on iOS because OS X doesn't care that the filename isn't exactly right.

Comment: You can try without image extension [UIImage imageNamed:@"WallPaper_01"]

Comment: This was the problem.  The capitalization on the image filenames was incorrect.  I don't believe I spent hours looking at this, I feel like an idiot!!  Thank you for helping me increase my knowledge.

Comment: Yep, I've been bit by the capitalization of image file names.  Thankfully, I recognized the syndrome right away and knew where to look, though.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be loading all images, then just using one. This may lead to memory problems in a real device. What you may want to do is something like this;

```
bgImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
            [@"WallPaper_01.png"],
            [@"WallPaper_02.png"],
            [@"WallPaper_03.png"],
            [@"WallPaper_04.png"],
            [@"WallPaper_05.png"],
                             nil];   
...
_myBackground.image = 
     [UIImage imageNamed:[bgImages objectAtIndex:currentBackground]];
```

Also, have a look at @rdelmar's comment about case sensitivity.

Comment: Thanks.  There is other code in the file that iterates through the array and increments the counter when a button is pressed to change the background picture.  I did not want to post the entire file for sake of clarity.  Thank you for your comment.